# MATLAB dealing with approximation-- singles to doubles

Tags: sql, sql-server, matlab, floating-point

I am pulling financial data into Matlab from SQL, where it is unfortunately stored as a 'Real' (which is an approximate data-type).

For example, a value got loaded into SQL as "96.194" which is the correct value (this could have any number of decimals 1-5). I know in SQL it is stored as something like 96.19400024 because it is an approximation, but SQL Server somehow knows to display it as 96.194.

When I pull it into matlab, it gets pulled in as 96.194, which is what I want. Unfortunately, it turns out it's not *actually* 96.194, as demonstrated:

```
>>price
price =
           96.194

>> price==96.194
ans =
     0

>> class(price)
ans =
single

>> double(price)
ans =
          96.1940002441406
```

So my question is, is there a way to convert a single to a double exactly as it appears as a single (i.e. truncate all the decimals which are the approximation? Note: I cannot just round it because I don't know how many decimals it's supposed to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vpa function lets you specify a number of significant (nonzero) digits that is different from the current digits setting. For example:

```
vpa(price, num_of_digits_required)
```

or in your case:

```
vpa(double(price),7)
```

(6 or 8 significant digits will yield the same result)

**Edit**

To use vpa you'll need the Symbolic Math Toolbox, there are alternatives found on the web, such as [this FEX file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725).

Comment: It looks like I don't have this function? I am on R2011B, and I'm not sure I have the symbolic math toolbox. Is there a way I can round to significant digits without the vpa function?

Comment: The vpa function requires the symbolic math toolbox, and was available as far as I know since Matlab 2008b. An alternative is to use an FEX option by John D'Ericco, see edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Single precision floating point values have only about 7 digits of precision (23 bit fractional component, log10(2^24) ≈ 7.225 decimal digits) so you could round off all but the 7 most significant digits.

Comment: Is there a function for doing this? I don't seem to have the vpa function that is designed for this. `N= num2str(price,7);
N= str2num(N);` comes to mind, but I'm not sure that's the "matlab" way of doing it.